# Retrive an array stored in database using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have an array: `productid = [1,2]`. Now I want to fetch data from product table by using this part of code:

```
$sql = 'SELECT name FROM product WHERE id=:id';
$s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
foreach($productid as $id)
{
  $s->bindValue(':id', $id);
  $s->execute();
}
```

when I returned the names as follow:

```
foreach($s as $row)
{
  $name[] = array(
      'name' => $row['name']
  );
}
```

I just got the product name of second id and didn't get both names.
What's the problem?

Comment: Try using an IN() statement. `WHERE id IN (:id)`. // Edit: I think PDO doesn't support binding arrays as argument though. You probably have to create a comma-separated string of the ids and bind that string.

Comment: @DanielM it won't work either

Comment: Looks like the title contradicts with question body. It seems that there are no arrays stored in your table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just got the product name of second id and didn't get both names. What's the problem?

You've got to put your `$name[] = $row['name'];` (yes, that's right notation) code inside of the foreach loop, as well as code that actually fetches the data.

You may also form a `IN()` statement that should be looks like `IN (?,?,?,?)` and run it in one query. Something like this (not tested):

```
$in   = trim(str_repeat('?,',count($productid)).",");
$sql  = "SELECT name FROM product WHERE id IN ($id)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($productid);
$name = $stmt->fetchAll();
```